# Как правильно вывести элементы массива используя итератор?

Tags: java, итераторы, delete

Ребят, помогите понять, почему вывод такой кривой? Я хочу получить вывод как указано в test9(), но выводит не то что надо. Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Код + тест программы прикрепляю ниже.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class ArrayImpl implements Array {
    Object[] array = new Object[0];

    @Override
    public void add(Object element) {
        Object[] arrayAdd = new Object[array.length + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayAdd.length; i++) {
            if (i == arrayAdd.length - 1) {
                arrayAdd[i] = element;
            } else {
                arrayAdd[i] = array[i];
            }
        }

        array = new Object[arrayAdd.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = arrayAdd[i];
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void set(int index, Object element) {
        Object[] arrSet = new Object[array.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < arrSet.length; i++) {
            if (i == index) {
                arrSet[i] = element;
            } else {
                arrSet[i] = array[i];
            }
        }
        array = new Object[arrSet.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < arrSet.length; i++) {
            array[i] = arrSet[i];
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object get(int index) {
        return array[index];
    }

    @Override
    public int indexOf(Object element) {
        int index = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] == element) {
                index = i;
                break;
            } else {
                index = -1;
            }
        }
        return index;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(int index) {
        Object[] arrRemove = new Object[array.length - 1];
        int current = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (i == index) {
                continue;
            } else {
                arrRemove[current] = array[i];
                current++;
            }
        }

        array = new Object[arrRemove.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < arrRemove.length; i++) {
            array[i] = arrRemove[i];
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        if (array != null) {
            array = new Object[0];
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return array.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Object> iterator() {
        return new IteratorImpl();
    }

    class IteratorImpl implements Iterator<Object> {
        int current = 0;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return array[current + 1] != null;
        }

        @Override
        public Object next() {
            return array[current++];
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            Object arrRem[] = new Object[size()-1];
            int lenght = current - 1;


            for (int i = lenght; i < arrRem.length; i++) {
                arrRem[i] = array[i];
            }

            array = new Object[arrRem.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                array[i] = arrRem[i];
            }

            current--;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (i == array.length - 1) stringBuilder.append(array[i]);
            else stringBuilder.append(array[i]).append(", ");
        }

        return "[" + stringBuilder.toString() + "]";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test9();
    }

    private static void test9() {

        Array array = new ArrayImpl();
        array.add("A");
        array.add("B");
        array.add("C");

        Iterator it = array.iterator();
        System.out.println(it.next());
        it.remove();
        System.out.println(it.next());
        it.remove();
        System.out.println(it.next());
        it.remove();
        System.out.println(array);

        /* an output must be as the following:
        *************************************
        A
        B
        C
        []
        *************************************
        */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поправьте метод remove() в итераторе. Можно так

```
@Override
public void remove() {
    int newLength = size()-1;
    Object[] arrRem = new Object[newLength];

    for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
        if(i != current-1){
            arrRem[i < current-1 ? i : i-1] = array[i];
        }
    }

    array = arrRem;
    current--;
}
```